# Dichotomy in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

How to prove over first order logic that if B has free variables $\{x_1, x_2\}$ it keeps the dichotomy theorem. namely:
 $$if\ \Gamma, A \vDash_v B ,\Gamma, \neg A \vDash_v B$$
$$ \  then \  \Gamma, \vDash_v B     $$

where: 

$\Gamma$ is a group of statements, A and B are statements.

$\vDash_v$ is means  that a formula is satisfied if and only if its universal closure is satisfied. or that B is satisfied by M for every assignment of $\{x_1, x_2\}$.

Comment: What does it mean $\vDash_v$ ?

Comment: added an explicit defenition of  ⊨

Comment: What have the free variables of $B$ got to do with this? Also, please give some indication that you have done some work on the problem: MSE is not a homework answering service.